# nodejs - readline interface prompt value modification

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

In nodejs, I am creating a CLI using readline module. initially I using the following code to start the prompt

```
let _interface = require('readline').createInterface{
input: process.stdin,
output: process.stdout,
prompt: '>'};
_interface.prompt();
/*some operation*/
_interface.prompt();
```

But I am trying to change the prompt icon from `>` to `$` as the user try's to change it. How can this be done, without *restarting the prompt*.

Comment: you want the cli user would be able to change the `>` to `$`

Comment: yes you are correct, @Aabid

Comment: How user can change he will simply enter `$` and will change? please explain more why you want to do this.

Comment: ok, lets consider the prompt is started the user `Welcome to CLI and in next line he has >`. now he is typing the command `change --$`, then from the next line CLI should use `$`. Hope you understood, for any more information let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `rl.setPrompt()` method.

Consider this example

```
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    prompt: '> '
});

rl.prompt();

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    if(line.trim()=='change --$'){
        rl.setPrompt('$');
    }
    rl.prompt();
}).on('close', () => {
    console.log('Have a great day!');
    process.exit(0);
});
```

I hope it will work for you.